# MessageHandler in JAR/WAR/EAR

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jar

I am making a PEP Server which intercepts the SOAP messages, and checks them against WS-Policies defined in a separate database. It is divided in 3 compontents:

1) PEP (Policy enforcemenet point) intercepts the messages with a message handler

2) sends it to the -> PDP (Policy decision point) decides which message gets through

3) this by using the PIP (Policy information point) which has a database with the policies.

If the policies are correct, the message gets send further to the web service. Now I was wondering how it would be possible to package this PEP in a JAR file (or WAR/EAR? I am new to this so I am not sure in which kind of package it should come). The PEP is a messagehandler, so the Web service will have to specify a @HandlerChain(file = "handler.xml")

Would it now be possible to include this PEP in the xml file, if its in contained in a jar file?

Comment: Are your PEP, PDP and PIP components all separate servers, or just different modules in the same (PEP) server?

Comment: @Perception they will be made as separate servers, each an ear file, but will most likely be run on the same glassfish application nonetheless but this should not be taken in account

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using JAX-WS for creating and invoking Java Web Services.

There's a nice tutorial about creating both a service and a client to invoke the service.  In your case, you'd want to zero in on the "A Simple JAX-WS Client" section.  They outline how to  do this with NetBeans but you can get the general idea and then revamp for your particular situation.

Here's the link for the tutorial: [Creating a Simple Web Service and Client with JAX-WS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html)

I'm thinking in your situation that you can just create a Java client that gets packaged as a JAR.

Comment: This will not work seeing as the project I am working on requires 3 different components. The PEP Server, PDP and PIP. They are all 3 a different package, communicating through SOAP and/or RMI. The Point is that you can deploy these in FRONT of the actual web service, protecting it with policies. The actual web service and the client trying to invoke have no meaning for me. The PEP server will be the message handler of the actual web service

Comment: @RoyTeeuwen - "The PEP server will be the message handler of the actual web service" - message handler as in Java Message Service (JMS) ?  The PEP server will need to be programmed in such a manner as to be able to handle the messages from the web service.  It sounds like JMS might be a good route for you as messages will be sent and consumed by the various components.

Comment: No the MessageHandler is a SOAPHandler, it intercepts SOAP messages in front of the actual web service, and can read/modify them before entering the actual web service